# "Element Should be Disabled" not working?

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

I am using Robot Framework and Selenium2Library. I am trying to check that given element is disabled. Code used is :

```
Element Should Be Disabled | //div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[4]
```

This code is giving me following error :

```
ERROR: Element //div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[4] is not an input.
```

Help in solving this problem would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was Used the "Get Element Attribute" keyword on the id of the element follow by the attribute I wanted to access so here it would be @disabled 
Get Element Attribute|id@disabled and stored it as a variable. You can then check if the value of that variable is disabled or not. Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear: Element ... is not an input.

The keyword is expecting an `<input/>` element.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you're implying that "disabled" is a property of an `<input>`-type HTML element, and as such if an HTML element is not an `<input>` element, it cannot be "disabled", is that correct?

Comment: That is not correct. It is known that `<input>` elements have the @disabled=[true|false] attribute, and probably the keyword is looking for it. Even so, if your `<span>` element did have the @disabled attribute, the keyword could fail because probably was designed to look only for `<input>`.

Comment: That is essentially what I was getting at, but thank you for the clarification.